# jQuery .live() - Whats wrong with this?

Tags: jquery

The past 3 days I've tried to get this simple example to work but whatever I try I just can't seem to understand where I'm going wrong...

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textEntry" /> <button>Go</button>
<ul id="list">
    <li>Text from the input field will appear below</li>
</ul>
```

jQUERY:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $enteredText = $('#textEntry').val();

    if($enteredText.length === 0) {
        alert('PLace an item in the field box');
    } else {        
        $newListItem = $('<li/>').html($enteredText).appendTo('#list');
    }

});

$('li').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if(event.type == mouseover) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } else {
        $(this).css('backgorund-color', 'transparent'); }
});
```

Ultimately what I'm looking to do is have a user input an item into the text field which would then append itself to the existing list (this works - no issues). The user can then hover over a specific entry causing the background to turn yellow on mouseover and transparent on mouseout (the issue).

Any help would be swell.

Thanks.

Comment: "What's wrong with this" -> It's deprecated ! And you're using it wrongly. Try on() instead. (and event.type is a string) -> [**Working FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N93xJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**event.type**](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/) gives you name of event in string so `mouseover` should be `"mouseover"`.

```
$('li').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if(event.type == "mouseover") {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } else {
        $(this).css('backgorund-color', 'transparent'); }
});
```

Edit `backgorund-color` should be `background-color`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I soon realised that there was 2 issues with my code - 1, that i hadn't put the mouseover in quotes and 2, the word background-color was misspelt. little things huh? thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (event.type == mouseover)
```

You don't have any variable named `mouseover`.